# Cordova plugin screen orientation not work

Tags: android, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have a problem with "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation", when I install this plugin and I add Android platform it error, but iOS fine, and I try to remove this plugin and add Android platform first and then I can't install "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" it always show fetch error.

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
System:

Node       : v8.1.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.1.0
```

Comment: what error do you get? can you add the output?

Comment: I ask in IONIC too: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/when-i-add-cordova-plugin-screen-orientation-it-error/99565

Comment: try `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation --save`

Comment: oh I solved it just downgrade to Cordova 6.5.0

Comment: `npm uninstall cordova ionic |
npm cache clean -f |
sudo npm install -g cordova@6.5.0`

Comment: @Shing, add your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cordova plugin add com.appodeal.plugin

if not work try this

> npm uninstall cordova ionic
>
> npm cache clean -f  sudo npm install -g
>
> cordova@6.5.0